# Having trouble using SelectCommand to select values in SQL database (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, selectcommand

So in an application I'm making, I have a selectCommand that is supposed to read the text within a textbox on a button click, and filters search results based off of the value.

Select command is.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT (bunch of columns) WHERE members.LastName LIKE '%@Ln%';
```

The value of @Ln is retrieved from code behind here:

```
public void searchButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Ln", inputLastName.Text);        
    }
```

**My goal is to select all records with last names containing whatever was entered into the last name text box**.  For example, I want "Mar", "Martinez", or a blank text box to all select somebody with the last name Martinez.  A blank text box should select all last names.

But I believe my problem lies in the syntax of the SelectCommand.  I've tested it without the single quotation marks, and many other variances of it to no avail.  If I leave just "WHERE members.LastName LIKE @Ln", it selects records where the last name is the exact value of inputLastName.Text, but as I mentioned, that's not what I'm looking for.  :(

I'm new to coding so please try to explain as clearly as possible, sorry if my problem was not articulated in the best way.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code as well?

Comment: I agree, we need your full code copy and pasted because this should work as written.

Comment: @MeanGreen Do you mean of the SelectCommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont forget the `"@"` in `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@Ln",`... and change your `SelectCommand` to:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT (bunch of column) WHERE members.LastName LIKE @Ln";

SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@Ln", '%' +  inputLastName.Text + '%');
```

so it should work.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm!  :)

One more question though.  You mentioned I should add the '@' when adding parameters.  The new code is working fine for me without the "@", but with it, I'm getting an error that says I "must declare scalar variables".  Do you know why that could be?